# Voltage drop calculation

Tags: impedance, conductors

The impedance of a single phase load with a supply voltage of 120 Volts AC is 2.80+j2.076Ω. The load draws 30 amps at 85% lagging power factor. Determine the size of the conductor used to supply power to the load if the conductors are uncoated copper wire run in steel conduit and the load is located 250 feet from the power source.

The answer is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### **I only didn't understand the last two steps.**

I mean to get the impedance in ohm/1000ft, he should have done it as follows:

Zc = 0.3 + j0.016 is already in ohm per 250ft.

So, multiplying it by 250ft, Zc = 75 + j4 ohm

Now, divide it by 1000ft,

Zc = 0.075 + j0.004

Am I right?

Comment: Why do expect that the resistance of long cable to be lower than that of a short one?

Comment: @Elec1 YES YES. I got it. You're absolutely right. Please make it official.